# adding custom icons in Magnolia CMS

Tags: templating, magnolia

I have problem adding custom icons in Magnolia CMS. I added png file in Templating Kit -> Resources in directory `templating-kit/themes/myTheme/img/icons/icons.png`.

In styles.css I have line: `background-image: url("../img/icons/icons.png");` but it doesn't work (firebug prints error: `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/magnoliaAuthor/resources/templating-kit/themes/myTheme/img/icons/icons.png"`

What have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance for every tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url seems valid. Go to the icon again, double click it to open it for editing and then look at the url produced in preview, that is the url you should use. Sometimes, probably depending on how you add the icon, it is accessible under `http://localhost:8080/magnoliaAuthor/resources/templating-kit/themes/myTheme/img/icons/icons/binary.png` instead of under the URI you tried.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Thank you very much :)
I don't know why, but css works when I used `url("../img/icons/icons/binary.png")`. Do you know why there are 2 directories named 'icons'? I have only one when I'm browsing resources using AdminCentral site.

Comment: one is name of the directory, the other is name of the file "binary" refers to the internal node storing the actual binary data. I've seen this few times, but so far i haven't figure out what is different and when it's enough to just use name of the file and when you need to include the name of data node (binary) ... I think it might depend on whether file name on the binary is set or not. When set and matching parent node it is pbly shortened and "binary" doesn't have to be used, otherwise it has to be used.

Comment: If you use following groovy script to upload the resource, you don't need to use binary: ... darn, it's too long to include. See it at http://pastie.org/8005291

Comment: I've had this problem a couple of times now, without seeing any pattern when it occurs and when not. So it's basically a bug, right?

Comment: IIRC, the behaviour is as follows:
- if the "fileName" property of the resource matches the name, you don't need to duplicate the name, if it doesn't match you need to use both or if that property is completely missing it is defaulted to name of the resource and you still need to use both. If all is set correctly in the resource (fileName exists and is matching the name) you don't even need to mention the "binary" part.

Comment: See http://demoauthor45.magnolia-cms.com/resources/templating-kit/themes/pop/img/icons/link/binary.png  vs. http://demoauthor45.magnolia-cms.com/resources/templating-kit/themes/pop/img/icons/link.png   (sry for splitting the comment, but it was getting too long).